# Boolean combinations of jquery events

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm wondering what is the best way to combine the basic jQuery events.

For example, if I want to run

```
function(e) {
  console.log(e.pageX)
}
```

when both of

```
$('selector').mousedown
```

and

```
$('selector').mousemove
```

or when

```
$('selector').mouseup
```

I'm aware of

```
$('selector').on('mousemove 'mouseup', ...)
```

but that makes my event handler respond to mousemovev or mouseup, without also verifying whether the mouse is down when 'mousemove' is validated.

is there a canonical way to combine the event listeners to reflect the desired logic?

EDIT:
For the application I'm building I'm trying to continually update a hidden field of a form as a user highlights text on a page, hence the desired combination of events. In my example I've tried to abstract away from the particular function of my project so that the essence of the question can be more apparent, and more readily adapted to satisfy futures readers' needs.

Comment: I changed the terminology to hopefully make the question clearer

Comment: Please be a lot more specifi regarding which events and exactly what it is you want to accomplish

Comment: I want to be able to do this regardless of what the specific events are. Basically I want to use logical operators to make arbitrary composite events, and I'm not sure if there's a conventional way of achieving that. Is there a better place for this question?

Comment: Event listeners can listen for multiple events but handler will fire for each individual event, so still need a lot more detail. Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Right, so that constitutes a logical 'or' connecting the multiple events. Is there a corresponding way to do 'and' short of nesting (because that seems unnatural for combining 'and' and 'or' as in the manner above)?

Comment: No it doesn't necessarily imply an OR. When are you going to explain the higher level objective?? Be Specific!

Comment: editing my question right now

Comment: So are you wanting to do something special when the mouse moves, while the mouse button is clicked?

Comment: Explain that in the question itself not in a paragraph long comment where it is much harder to read and may go unnoticed by other readers of the question. All your abstraction is just muddying up what the actual objective is

Comment: Suspectt what you actually want is [`getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) inside a mouseup. check it's length and if it has length you know user selected something

Comment: Yes, I originally used getSelection inside a mouseup. But that does not continually update the form as the user drags across the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this code a try. I imagine this is close to what you want. Basically I only bind a mousemove function when the mousedown is fired. The mouseup is to handle end of text-highlighting. Good luck!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).mousedown(function(){
 $(document).bind( "mousemove", function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
 });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
 $(document).unbind("mousemove");
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

Comment: It was this use of 'bind' that I was looking for.